# timeout function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, timeout

I have the following code, which is supposed to check if jQuery is loaded, and avoid running my jQuery function until it is loaded.

It doesn't seem to work, I think the Timeout function isn't running or passing the right function through it (runwhenjqueryloaded).

I've spent way more time on this than the client is budgeted for, so any quick help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

```
function runwhenjqueryloaded(){ 
  if (window.jQuery) {
    console.log("jquery rocks");
    //jquery exists, do what you want 
    $(function() {
      $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        animationSpeed: 400,
        animationLoop: false,
        itemWidth: 210,
        itemMargin: 5,
        minItems: 1,
        maxItems: 4       
      });
    });

  } else {
    setTimeout(function() {runwhenjqueryloaded(); }, 60); 
  }
}
runwhenjqueryloaded();
```

Comment: well.. it easy to check, isn't it. Just add another console.log() inside your function that you pass to setTimeout. What might be happening is that jquery is actually not loaded. On the other hand, are you loading jquery some other way then with the script tag in index.html?

Comment: Just put the jQuery script above this script in the HTML. Also, you can just call `setTimeout` as `setTimeout(runwhenjqueryloaded, 60)`

Comment: Just note that `setTimeout()` is in milliseconds. So you're setting it to 60 milliseconds. If you want seconds, it would be 60000.

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout is working just fine in your code, but you could write it simpler:

```
setTimeout(runwhenjqueryloaded,60)
```

Aren't you having an error somewhere else?
Try to debug or put a console.log at the beginning of runwhenjqueryloaded() and another just after "else".

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use setInterval instead.

function bootstrap($) {
    $(function() {
       $('.flexslider').flexslider({
           animation: "slide",
           animationSpeed: 400,
           animationLoop: false,
           itemWidth: 210,
           itemMargin: 5,
           minItems: 1,
           maxItems: 4       
       });
    });
}

var jqCheck = setInterval(function() {
   if (window.jQuery !== undefined) {
       bootstrap(window.jQuery);
       clearInterval(jqCheck);
   }
}, 60);
```

Comment: This worked perfectly...except now I need a way to load jQuery if it hasn't loaded (This is being integrated in a 3rd party platform, and for some reason it just doesn't always load jQuery...).

I think I understand what you did with the setInterval function - you wrapped the flexslider in the bootstrap function, and then checked for jQuery,so that the bootstrap doesn't run unless window.jQuery returns true, right? So at what point in that code would I add code to now force load jQuery, and then run that check again? Thanks so much!